# Laravel 5.4: groupedBy id and count the quantity of each product

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have a filtration query looks like this.

```
public function index( Request $request ) {
        $dateFrom = $request->get( 'dateFrom' );
        $dateTo   = $request->get( 'dateTo' );
        $status   = $request->get( 'orderState' );

        $orders = ( new OrderList() )
            ->whereHas( 'orderDetail', function ( $query ) {
                $query->where( 'supplier_id', Auth::guard( 'supplier' )->user()->id );
            } )
            ->with( 'deliveryList' )
            ->with( 'orderDetail' )
            ->when( $dateFrom, function ( $query ) use ( $dateFrom, $dateTo ) {
                $query->whereBetween( 'created_at', [ $dateFrom, $dateTo ] );
            } )
            ->when( $status, function ( $query ) use ( $status ) {
                $query->where( 'order_state_id', $status )->get();
            } )->get();

        $productList = $orders->orderDetail;
        dd( $productList );
        //Order Status
        $orderStates = OrderState::listsTranslations( 'states' )->pluck( 'states', 'id' )->toArray();


        return view( 'supplierComponents.order_list', compact( 'orders', 'orderStates' ) );
    }
```

now this query will output a list of orders with the orders details.
what I need is group the products in each order and get the quantity

the last view should be something like this

```
product name           quantity
-------------------------------
Tea                      5
-------------------------------
juice                    3
-------------------------------
```

**My Models**
OrderLst

```
public function orderDetail() {
        return $this->hasMany( OrderDetail::class, 'order_id' );
    }
```

**Update**
thought I will never get it the right way from `controller` and I didn't think about try to get it in the blade directly

so What I did is shifted to the blade trying to make it there.

Here what I did

```
@foreach($orders as $order)
    @foreach($order->orderDetail as $items)
       <tr>
         <td>{!! $items->quantity !!}</td>
         <td>{!! $items->product_name !!}</td>
       </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Now I am getting all the products listed as I need but try to `Group` them
like that

```
@foreach($orders as $order)
      @foreach($order->orderDetail->groupBy('product_id') as $items)
          <tr>
            <td>{!! $items->quantity !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $items->product_name !!}</td>
          </tr>
      @endforeach
@endforeach
```

> Got: Property [quantity] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: can u show ur models to us, to understand the relationships to `product`

Comment: @arun no products models here its the `OrderDetail` which has the products details. and I just added it to my question.

Comment: in which table u have `quantity`?

Comment: I have it in `order_details`

Answer (score 0):

```
$orders = ( new OrderList() )
        ->whereHas( 'orderDetail', function ( $query ) {
            $query->where( 'supplier_id', Auth::guard( 'supplier' )->user()->id );
        } )
        ->with( 'deliveryList' )
        ->with(['orderDetail' => function ($query) {
                $query->select(DB::raw('*, sum(quantity) as quantity_sum'))->groupBy('product_id')->get();
            }])
        ->when( $dateFrom, function ( $query ) use ( $dateFrom, $dateTo ) {
            $query->whereBetween( 'created_at', [ $dateFrom, $dateTo ] );
        } )
        ->when( $status, function ( $query ) use ( $status ) {
            $query->where( 'order_state_id', $status )->get();
        } )->get();
```

Untested.

Comment: thanks but here is the results `"quantity_sum" => "4"` which is wrong it just counted the query and the results is 4, Can't be something separated from the first query like using `productList = $orders->orderDetail;` and get the results and make the grouping and get the quantity

Comment: use groupby `product_id`

Comment: if u show the table structure, then i will give u clear query